# three.js - FXAA giving error upon update from r65 to r68

Tags: three.js, fxaa

I just switched from r65 to r68 of three.js and I am getting this error in the browser console when using the FXAA post processing shader:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog() WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'vUv' not read by fragment shader... three.js:25545

I tried the same code with r65 and the error does not occur. The Shader appears to be working fine, but I don't like getting errors in the console. The following is the relevant code:

```
// COMPOSER

this.renderTargetScene = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( this.width, this.height );
this.renderTargetScene.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
this.renderTargetScene.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
this.renderTargetScene.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;
this.renderTargetScene.stencilBuffer = true;

this.sceneComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( this.renderer, this.renderTargetScene );

this.sceneCubeUnderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( this.sceneCube, this.cameraCube );
this.sceneCubeUnderPass.renderToScreen = false;
this.scenePass = new THREE.RenderPass( this.scene, this.camera );
this.scenePass.renderToScreen = false;
this.scenePass.clear = false;

this.effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader );
this.effectFXAA.uniforms.resolution.value = new THREE.Vector2( 1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight );

this.effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
this.effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

this.sceneComposer.addPass( this.sceneCubeUnderPass );
this.sceneComposer.addPass( this.scenePass );
this.sceneComposer.addPass( this.effectFXAA );
this.sceneComposer.addPass( this.effectCopy );

onWindowResize: function() {

    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.height = window.innerHeight;

    iss.windowHalfX = this.width / 2;
    iss.windowHalfY = this.height / 2;

    iss.camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
    iss.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    iss.cameraCube.aspect = this.width / this.height;
    iss.cameraCube.updateProjectionMatrix();

    iss.renderer.setSize( this.width, this.height );

    iss.effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set(1 / ( this.width ), 1 / ( this.height ));
    iss.sceneComposer.setSize( this.width, this.height );

},

render: function(){

    var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();

    iss.cameraCube.rotation.copy( iss.camera.rotation );

iss.sceneComposer.render( 0.1 );

},
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a warning.

You can fix it by editing `examples/js/shaders/FXAAShader.js` and removong all lines that reference `vUv`, as that varying is not used.

three.js r.68

Comment: I guess we should remove it in the lib too? :U